# Powers of primitive roots.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, primitive-roots

Let  $w= \cos\frac{2k\pi}{n} + i \sin\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ be a primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, ie, $w^n=1$ and $w^m \neq 1$ for $m \leq n$. Then the powers
$$1, w, w^2, \ldots, w^{n-1}$$
are all the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity.

**Comments:** I tried by use the fact that if $w_0 = (\cos\frac{2\pi}{n} + i \sin\frac{2\pi}{n})$ then the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity are $1, w_0, w_0^2, \ldots, w_0^{n-1}$. This case is the case in that $k=1$ in the problem. The way forward would be this using $\mod{n}$? Or there would be one where I would not need the result I commented.

Comment: I wonder if you saw the letter $\omega$ in a book and thought it was $w. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is roadmap:

- $1, w, w^2, \ldots, w^{n-1}$ are $n$th roots of unity.
- $1, w, w^2, \ldots, w^{n-1}$ are all different. This is the crucial point.
- There are exactly $n$ complex $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: My difficulty is in the second step, how to prove it?

Comment: @Croos, otherwise, $w^j = w^k$ implies  $w^m=1$ for $0<m<n$.